# Proximity sensor notification not called in controller with AVQueuePlayer ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, proximitysensor

I have a controller with AVQueuePlayer, here i have implemented proximity sensor code but here the notification of proximity does not get fire for some reason. Below is the code that i have implemented.

```
UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.proximityChanged), name: UIDevice.proximityStateDidChangeNotification, object: UIDevice.current)
```

the below method does not get called

```
@objc func proximityChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let device = notification.object as? UIDevice {
            print("\(device) detected!")
        }
    }
```

Note:- this method works in all the controller except the controller where video player is implemented. Any help will be great.!!

Comment: Do you implement `UIDevice.current.isProximityMonitoringEnabled = true` in AppDelegate?

Comment: @AhmetSinaUstem yes